# How do make static controls in sharepoint?

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have a web part with SpGridview control .

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="grid" AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="true"  CssClass="ms-listviewtable"  ClientIDMode="Static"
runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"></SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

I defined a static function , when i use this grid in this ,i get error

**An object reference is required for the nonstatic field**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not related to SharePoint anyway.

In C#, Static members can operate only on static data and call static methods of the
defining class. If you attempt to make use of nonstatic class data or call a nonstatic method of the class within a static member’s implementation,you will get error.

To use the grid in static method, you need to create instance of the webpart class and then use it.